# Summing Prices on Orders that Have Happened in a Certain Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I am having difficulty with a query, I have a large number of orders that I am extracting the month and year from, and need to sum all of the prices within each month and year.  The only way I can come up with a solution is to iterate through and make a large number of costly comparisons, and that seems to defeat the purpose of a relational database.  The price is being calculated in the query I have, as a discount is often applied on the subtotal.  I have all the necessary tables joined and matching up, but because of the price calculation I cannot use the built in SUM() function.  Thank you, in advance!

EDIT: Here's the code, I'm super scattered today apparently.  That's absolutely on me, thank you for staying with me:

```
`SELECT dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderNo
    ,dbo.SalesOrder.CustomerID
    ,(dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice * (1 - dbo.Invoice.DiscountPct / 100)) AS [Price]
    ,dbo.Customers.NAME AS [Customer Name]
    ,dbo.Customers.SalesRepID
    ,dbo.Employees.FirstName + dbo.Employees.LastName AS [SalesRepName]
    ,dbo.Estimate.DateCreated AS [Date Quoted]
    ,dbo.SalesOrder.OrderDate AS [Date Ordered]
    ,dbo.Invoice.BillingDate AS [Date Invoiced]
    ,MONTH(dbo.Estimate.DateCreated) AS [Month Quoted]
    ,MONTH(dbo.SalesOrder.OrderDate) AS [Month Ordered]
    ,MONTH(dbo.Invoice.BillingDate) AS [Month Invoiced]
    ,YEAR(dbo.Estimate.DateCreated) AS [Year Quoted]
    ,YEAR(dbo.SalesOrder.OrderDate) AS [Year Ordered]
    ,YEAR(dbo.Invoice.BillingDate) AS [Year Invoiced]
FROM SalesOrder
INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.SalesOrderID = SalesOrder.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN InvoiceDetails ON InvoiceDetails.InvoiceID = Invoice.InvoiceID
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = SalesOrder.CustomerID
INNER JOIN SalesReps ON Customers.SalesRepID = SalesReps.SalesRepID
INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.EmployeeID = SalesReps.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Estimate ON Estimate.EstimateID = SalesOrder.EstimateID
WHERE dbo.Invoice.Approved = '1'
    AND (YEAR(dbo.Invoice.BillingDate) >= YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)
    AND (YEAR(dbo.Estimate.DateCreated) >= YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)
    AND (YEAR(dbo.SalesOrder.OrderDate) >= YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)`
```

Comment: not sure what the problem is but just summing up prices and grouping by month-year should be fine.

Comment: If you posted a sample schema, with some sample data, it would be useful. But this seems like a very straightforward question, so I'm wondering if there's something non-obvious going on?

Comment: Can you provide sample input dataset and expected output?

Comment: If I have two orders Q1 and Q2, which both came in during January of 2017, both with a price of $500 I should get $1000, January and 2017 back.  I can't seem to reference the price I calculated in the query for SUM(), as it is calculated in the statement, and do not know how to go about addressing this.  Sorry to the first two responders, I lost track of my thoughts posting the initial question and left out most of the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any other information, is there a reason you can't do something like this?

```
SELECT YEAR(ORDER_DATE) AS [Year], MONTH(ORDER_DATE) AS [Month], SUM(AMOUNT) AS [Total]
  FROM Orders
 GROUP BY YEAR(ORDER_DATE), MONTH(ORDER_DATE)
 ORDER BY YEAR(ORDER_DATE), MONTH(ORDER_DATE)
```

Assuming the table name is "Orders" and it has columns "ORDER_DATE" as a datetime, and "AMOUNT" as a numeric value.

---

Based on your updated query showing the computation of the price, a simple way around things is to just create a CTE (Common Table Expression) out of your existing query, and then SELECT/GROUP BY that... something like this:

```
WITH sales AS (
    SELECT dbo.SalesOrder.SalesOrderNo
        ,dbo.SalesOrder.CustomerID
        ,(dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice * (1 - dbo.Invoice.DiscountPct / 100)) AS [Price]
        ,dbo.Customers.NAME AS [Customer Name]
        ,dbo.Customers.SalesRepID
        ,dbo.Employees.FirstName + dbo.Employees.LastName AS [SalesRepName]
        ,dbo.Estimate.DateCreated AS [Date Quoted]
        ,dbo.SalesOrder.OrderDate AS [Date Ordered]
        ,dbo.Invoice.BillingDate AS [Date Invoiced]
        ,MONTH(dbo.Estimate.DateCreated) AS [Month Quoted]
        ,MONTH(dbo.SalesOrder.OrderDate) AS [Month Ordered]
        ,MONTH(dbo.Invoice.BillingDate) AS [Month Invoiced]
        ,YEAR(dbo.Estimate.DateCreated) AS [Year Quoted]
        ,YEAR(dbo.SalesOrder.OrderDate) AS [Year Ordered]
        ,YEAR(dbo.Invoice.BillingDate) AS [Year Invoiced]
    FROM SalesOrder
    INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.SalesOrderID = SalesOrder.SalesOrderID
    INNER JOIN InvoiceDetails ON InvoiceDetails.InvoiceID = Invoice.InvoiceID
    INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = SalesOrder.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN SalesReps ON Customers.SalesRepID = SalesReps.SalesRepID
    INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.EmployeeID = SalesReps.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Estimate ON Estimate.EstimateID = SalesOrder.EstimateID
    WHERE dbo.Invoice.Approved = '1'
        AND (YEAR(dbo.Invoice.BillingDate) >= YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)
        AND (YEAR(dbo.Estimate.DateCreated) >= YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)
        AND (YEAR(dbo.SalesOrder.OrderDate) >= YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1)
)
SELECT [Month Ordered], [Year Ordered], SUM([Price]) AS TotalOrderedPrice
  FROM Sales
 GROUP BY [Month Ordered], [Year Ordered]
 ORDER BY [Month Ordered], [Year Ordered]
```

This creates a CTE named "sales" using your original query verbatum, and then uses the CTE in the SELECT at the bottom to do grouping and ordering on (including SUMMING the calculated price) on the results of that query. This is simple 'syntactic sugar' that makes expressing this kind of stuff a lot easier than if you had to rework the query to sum on computed values or sub-selects or what-have-you, and is a useful trick.

Comment: The issue is that I'm calculating the price in the query, as it's not in the database and I am forbidden from modifying it.  It won't allow me to calculate the cost in the statement, and unfortunately being new to SQL I'm not sure if a nested SELECT statement would fix it or if there is a better option, not to mention how to format it.

Comment: Well, I'm not even sure what you're saying here, so providing an example, showing the SQL you have or have tried, the schema, etc. would be very useful. Here I've answered the question that you asked. Apparently you meant to ask a different question, so you should edit your question to be more accurate.

Comment: The price is calculated in the query I am writing, I have a subtotal and discount rate that I'm calculating into a final price: `(dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice * (1 - dbo.Invoice.DiscountPct / 100)) AS [Price]`  This seems to be preventing me from placing the SUM() on the price, from what I can tell.  I do appreciate your answer as it did settle some of my worries about the query, and I'm sorry to have left these details out (been sitting here trying to figure this out for too long, I suppose).  Is there a way to reference the price in the same SELECT statement?

Comment: @Kishi I've updated the answer to show one possible solution (the easiest translation) using a CTE.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for the help!  I've been banging my head on the wall all day over this.